# Intellij complains of incorrect configuration for django project

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

Whenever I run my python django application in Intellij, it shows me a dialog box saying configuration is incorrect and gives me an option to `edit` or `run anyway`.

Following is the screenshot of my configuration. Not sure what is it that I am missing.

[image]

Update: It does show intermittently in the same configuration dialog box that Django project root is not configured and I am not sure how I can do that. Also, when I run the project anyway, it says,

> No manage.py file specified in Settings->Django Support

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is the above issue fixable directly but after pressing run on manage.py to create a new configuration and providing it script parameters `runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`, it worked without errors.

In the above older configuration, Intellij was running a different command

```
python3.5 /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/myorg/bin/django-admin.py runserver 8000
```